# Set value of previously declared variables in Dynamic Select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I'm working with a piece of dynamic SQL, posted below.

During testing when I Print @Query and run it, my variables get assigned.  But when that extra level of indirection is added, and the @Query is run using Exec, the Select statement at the end returns nulls.

```
DECLARE @ETFirstPart varchar(max)
DECLARE @ETContactLines varchar(max)
DECLARE @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine varchar(max)
DECLARE @ETLastPart varchar(max)

SET @Query = N'SELECT @ETFirstPart = piv.HBAppCli1, @ETContactLines = piv.HBAppCli2a, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine = piv.HBAppCli2b, @ETLastPart = piv.HBAppCli3
                from (select EmailMessageType, EmailBody
                        FROM ' + @dbSharedServer + '.dbShared.dbo.EmailMessage e
                    ) ac
                pivot (max(EmailBody)
                        for EmailMessageType in (HBAppCli1, HBAppCli2a, HBAppCli2b, HBAppCli3)
                    ) piv'
PRINT @Query
EXEC (@Query)

SELECT @ETFirstPart, @ETContactLines, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine, @ETLastPart
```

How can I get the variables assigned to the selected values in the dynamic select?

Comment: You need to use sp_executesql to get the output values of the select query stored to the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sp_executesql. Something like below:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'SELECT @ETFirstPart = piv.HBAppCli1, @ETContactLines = piv.HBAppCli2a, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine = piv.HBAppCli2b, @ETLastPart = piv.HBAppCli3
            from (select EmailMessageType, EmailBody
                    FROM ' + @dbSharedServer + '.dbShared.dbo.EmailMessage e
                ) ac
            pivot (max(EmailBody)
                    for EmailMessageType in (HBAppCli1, HBAppCli2a, HBAppCli2b, HBAppCli3)
                ) piv'

 exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@ETFirstPart varchar(max) out, @ETContactLines varchar(max) out, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine varchar(max) out, @ETLastPart varchar(max) out', @ETFirstPart out, @ETContactLines out, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine out, @ETLastPart out
SELECT @ETFirstPart, @ETContactLines, @ETAlternateContactOnlyLine, @ETLastPart
```

Comment: Aaah, I see!  I will try Thursday aft when I'm back at the client, and confirm the answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Note to others:  the nvarchar(max) type is important - that's what sq_executesql expects.  Varchar(max) won't work, and gives you an error about the @statement parameter.